# Where to place controls in user account form?

Tags: usability, forms, login

I'm creating an user account window for my instant messenger application.
[image]

User have to:

- enter name, password, server
- press button "Connect".

Also user can:

- close this form without connection
- enter advanced options (f.e. port, encoding).

And this form will show:

- connection result, errors
- warnings, tips for user (f.e. if some field will be clear)

I can not imagine how to show all this here.
For example: make "Cancel" button or "Back" arrow in top left corner. Or maybe make "X" button in top right?

Could you help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your case would like to recommend you for the connection results, errors, warnings and all of these stuff inside a hidden message then appear like this:[image]

For the inputs try to put validation for username (minlength, maxlength, etc..) and password (minlength, maxlength, encrypted).

Connect button make it little bit active like either of these two images:

[image]

Forget to add, these are Bootstrap components.